# Use of OR operator on Cloudkit predicate

Tags: swift, predicate, cloudkit

I have a cloudkit record with 5 fields:

```
Active
User1
User2
User3
User4
```

I am trying to pick the record where one of the 4 user fields match with the userID variable.

Only one other the 4 user fields will match the userID variable.

This is the code I am using:

```
var userID = "0984093843897"

predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userID1 = %@ OR userID2 = %@ OR userID3 = %@ OR userID4 = %@ AND active = %@", userID, userID, userID, userID, true)
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is something similar to the statement bellow:

```
if userID1 == userID || userID2 == userID || userID3 == userID || userID4 == userID && active = true
```

Unfortunatelly cloudkit is returning an error for the predicate format. I am not sure if what I am trying to do here is achievable with cloudkit predicates or if there is a better way for doing it.

Most of the examples I found here on stack deals with predicates with AND operators, not sure how to use an OR operator. Looking at Apple Docs it does not exist, so not sure if there a work around that.

Comment: You should include the error message in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Kit's `CKQuery` doesn't support `OR` in a predicate. See the documentation for `CKQuery`. It shows all the supported predicate operators and while `AND` and `NOT` are supported, `OR` is not.

One possible replacement for `OR` would be `IN`. I've only seen this where you wish to see if a single field contains one of several values. But your case is in reverse. Try the following but it may not work.

```
var userID = "0984093843897"
NSPredicate(format:"%@ IN { %K, %K, %K, %K } AND active = true", userID, "userID1", "userID2", "userID3", "userID4"]
```

Comment: I know this has been marked as correct however in my tests, although the predicate is created, when you try to apply it to the CKQuery, an error is reported stating that "0984093843897" is not an evaluated object expression.

So did someone actually get this to work?