# Unable to use OR operator with 2 predicates

Tags: swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I have two predicates that when both used individually work absolutely fine, however when I try to combine them in an OR, I get:

<CKError 0x600000c71320: "Invalid Arguments" (12/1009); "Invalid predicate: Unexpected expression: etc....

These are the two predicates that both work individually:

```
let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "creatorUserRecordID IN %@ AND NOT(recordID IN %@)", referencesForUsersIFollow, cachedUserAccountsRecordIDS)
let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "creatorUserRecordID IN %@ AND recordID IN %@ AND modificationDate > %@", referencesForUsersIFollow, cachedUserAccountsRecordIDS, userAccountsCacheLastUpdated as CVarArg)
```

And I use this to combine them, which is when the problem comes in:

```
let combinedPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1, predicate2])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of OR operator on Cloudkit predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311758/use-of-or-operator-on-cloudkit-predicate)

Comment: So is there a way to achieve this with CloudKit?

Comment: Also these questions don’t show anything that says cq query doesn’t support it. They just come to the conclusion

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquery, scroll down to "Table 1 Supported predicate operators"

Comment: The answer says "See the documentation for CKQuery. It shows all the supported predicate operators and while AND and NOT are supported, OR is not.".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CloudKit compound query (query with OR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30952390/cloudkit-compound-query-query-with-or)